# syn flood attack on port 80

Tags: linux, centos, apache2

For the last two days I am facing a syn flood attack
and continue to get following messages:

> Oct 27 00:52:58 server2 kernel: [ 1356.539680] possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
>   Oct 27 00:53:58 server2 kernel: [ 1416.545865] possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
>   Oct 27 00:54:58 server2 kernel: [ 1476.546692] possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
>   Oct 27 00:55:58 server2 kernel: [ 1536.547742] possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.
>   Oct 27 00:56:58 server2 kernel: [ 1596.549753] possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.

At this time sites are not loading.

I am on CentOS Linux and I have tried the following :

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377706/iptables-prevent-flooding

Answer (score 2):

you should make these change too
On Linux, those are some settings you can use to enable and set up SYN Cookies efficiently:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies
echo 2048 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog
echo 3 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_synack_retries
```

To make those settings load automatically on startup, add those lines to the file /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 3
```

Comment: i made above changes Still getting same problem ,it happening to a particular account .                                                                                      netstat -tuna | grep :80 | grep SYN_RECV                                               this results shows results from our server ip. when null routed this ip syn flood problem stopped, when i removed  again started

Comment: Just to get a better idea, how much SYN_RECV per second do you see? Are them from different IP's or most come from the same?

Comment: it nearly comes to 100 and we enabled  cloud flare free account so all this shows cloud flare ip(different  IPs i think so)